# Best way to invert a n x n Matrix

Tags: java, matrix, matrix-inverse

I was wondering what's the correct and best way on Java to invert a (double) 2D matrix. My input(MatrixToBeInverted) is a double[][] ,filled and over 20x20. Using code like this will throw me errors.

```
invMatrix = LinearAlgebra.inverse(MatrixToBeInverted);
```

I read that the .inverse() function is deprecated.

When using Apache Commons 2.4 with such code:

```
System.out.println(new org.apache.commons.math3.linear.LUDecomposition(
        MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(MatrixToBeInverted)
        ).getSolver().getInverse());
```

I get such error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.linear.SingularMatrixException:     matrix is singular

at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.LUDecomposition$Solver.solve(LUDecomposition.java:335)

at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.LUDecomposition$Solver.getInverse(LUDecomposition.java:383)

at MatrixCalc.calculateMatrix(MatrixCalc.java:405)

at MatrixCalc.main(MatrixCalc.java:932)
```

But as a matter of fact I know that the Input matrix can be inverted.

Comment: What library are you using? Java has no standard `LinearAlgebra` class.

Comment: The following -> org.math.array.LinearAlgebra

Comment: Is that [JMathTools](http://jmathtools.berlios.de/doku.php)? Or [JMathArray](https://code.google.com/p/jmatharray/)? I'm not seeing anything saying the `inverse` method is deprecated.

Comment: have you declared your variables as double[][]?? what errors does it throw?

Comment: Nope, Jama http://jmatharray.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jmatharray/doc/org/math/array/LinearAlgebra.html

Comment: If i try to use this input matrix on a online calculator it will work but not on Java. Errors -> java.lang.RuntimeException: Matrix is singular.
 at Jama.LUDecomposition.solve(LUDecomposition.java:282)
 at Jama.Matrix.solve(Matrix.java:815)
 at Jama.Matrix.inverse(Matrix.java:833)
 at org.math.array.LinearAlgebra.inverse(Unknown Source)

Comment: And yes, the variables are stored as double[][]